# Why don't we experience objects a little displaced from their actual positions when using eyeglasses as an effect of refraction?

Tags: refraction, geometric-optics, vision

We all know that as a result of **refraction**,when passing through a **transparent/translucent object**, the **rays get slightly displaced from their actual path.**

***So why don't people who wear eyeglasses observe slightly displaced objects?***

I myself can sense even the tip of a leaf to an accuracy that I can touch it without any confusion while wearing myopic eyeglasses of very high power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Human perception learns to correct the image produced by the retina. When I first wore reading glasses, I did find they distorted the room around me. Now they do not seem to. Studies have even been done in which people wear devices which invert the image, so that it appears upside down. After a while wearing the device, the human brain flips the image, so that it again appears the right way up.

Comment: Thanks @Charles Francis, So I guess it is the human mind that is doing the necessary corrections.

Answer (score 2):

People with glasses have the lenses covering their whole eyes. The light they are viewing is refracted, but when the glasses are being worn, they do not notice this refraction since there is no reference point that they can look at (outside the frame of the glasses) to compare the refracted image with the original external objects. But if you were to lower the glasses so that you can see both the image produced by the lenses, and the external objects, you will definitely see a difference between this and the refracted image. In fact, some people who wear glasses may even experience a distortion of their peripheral vision since the glasses image objects directly in front and not on the sides.

Another thing to note is that people who wear glasses for the first time will notice changes in depth perception and sizes/distances may seem different.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Dr jh! I But what about when we try to reach out to these objects? We do not face confusion, right?

Comment: Have you tried to play basketball with and without glasses corrected for short-sightedness? If you have you will experience a change in depth perception.

Comment: There might be slight depth perception difficulty at the start

Comment: yes I have observed this when I am going to remove or wear my glasses after a long time of breakor at the edges of glasses